# msinfo32.exe can't collect information on a sharepoint page ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, msinfo32

I am creating a new process on my Sharepoint web application. I've run the same command as below and works on my OS but not on my web app. I wanted to know why and if this is even possible. Here's code that creates the process.

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"report.txt"); 
Process proc = new Process();
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "msinfo32.exe";
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/report " + filePath;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
proc.Close();
```

It creates a file with every filed as `Can't collect information`, example:

```
Can't Collect Information   
[Hardware Resources]
[Conflicts/Sharing]
Can't Collect Information   
[DMA]
```

Am I doing it wrong, are there settings to enable on sharepoint in order to run msinfo32?

WMI is enabled on my OS.

Comment: `string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"report.txt"));` are you sure you are not getting a compile error here ..remove the last `)`

Comment: I verified that this works from a web page.. can you post the web page event that you are trying to launch this from along with the .cs file's header

Comment: @MethodMan thanks for taking a look into this. This completely worked for me when I started an aspx page, a 4.5.1 .Net project. however not when I copied the code over to a Sharepoint server. The event that triggers this is a click handler from an image button. The image button is within a datatable's column.

Comment: can you show the code / event that's not work perhaps there is something being done incorrectly..

Comment: The fact that msinfo generates a file means that the program ran successfully. I'm tempted to think that sharepoint restricts process calls that try to access hardware information. I hope there is a work around

Comment: there has to be an `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` or something

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Sharepoint requires an elevated security state to run this command. Wrapping the code in this helped run `msinfo32.exe`. Thanks to Amal Hashim and Method Man for recommending this

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    //Your code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I went to the directory where my debug folder is running a console app on my side
here is what I did and it work.. 
change the name of your `Report.txt` to `out.log` open the `out.log` file and just type anything in it.. save it and close it .. and run the following code below and you will se the `SystemInformation` window pop up. add this in the `Page_Load` event to test it

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "out.log"); 
Process proc = new Process();
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "msinfo32.exe";
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/out " + filePath;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
proc.Close();
```

I just tested this from my Page_Load in my web page and it works like a charm.. what you need to add to the header of the webpage that you are launching it from is the following

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
```

Comment: Did you try this on a SharePoint page?

Comment: John yes this works from executing an exe from sharepoint.. I am not sure what the OP is doing but I tried even another way of doing it and it worked also..

Comment: I was thinking it might not work in the trust model that SharePoint uses.

Comment: which could be correct but I ran mine locally that could be the difference in regards to what you are thinking as well..